# Как обновить Gradle в Intellij IDEA? Ошибка Unsupported Project JDK 19

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

При создании проекта в IntelliJ IDEA вылезает данное окно. На данный момент самая свежая версия Gradle 7.5.1. Как обновить систему сборки в данной IDE? Возможно, нужно установить версию JDK пониже? Где можно почитать о JDK vX.X.X -> совместима с Gradle vX.X.X?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем вопросе содержится сразу несколько проблем. Чтобы этот вопрос был полезен другим посетителям сайта, необходимо в одном вопросе формулировать лишь одну проблему. Пожалуйста, [переформулируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1456433/edit) вопрос, чтобы он был сфокусирован на одной проблеме. Что касается апгрейда версии Gradle в проекте, сделать это можно из командной строки с помощью команды `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.5.1`. Но для начала вам нужно поставить JDK ниже 19.

Comment: Сформулируйте только одну проблему в текущем вопросе, а остальные проблемы задайте в [отдельном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: В текущем вопросе я у вас вижу ошибку Unsupported Project JDK, вам в первую очередь нужно не обновлять Gradle, а сначала понизить версию JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент Java 19 не поддерживается системой сборки Gradle. Об этом сказано [на сайте Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html):

> A Java version between 8 and 18 is required to execute Gradle. Java 19 and later versions are not yet supported.

На той же [странице](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) есть таблица совместимости версий Gradle с версиями JDK:

| Версия Java | Минимальная версия Gradle |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 2.0 |
| 9 | 4.3 |
| 10 | 4.7 |
| 11 | 5.0 |
| 12 | 5.4 |
| 13 | 6.0 |
| 14 | 6.3 |
| 15 | 6.7 |
| 16 | 7.0 |
| 17 | 7.3 |
| 18 | 7.5 |
| 19 | 7.6 |

Чтобы продолжить работать с Gradle, понизьте вашу версию JDK до 18 или ниже.

**Update:** Gradle 7.6 поддерживает Java 19. Вы можете продолжать пользоваться Java 19, если обновите Gradle до последней версии.